# Keycloak - request user to verify email address through api

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-nodejs-connect

**Desired result**:

User should be able to register and then he should be able to login thrugh a mobile app (event if the email address isn't verified), the app shows a warning that email isn't verified and some app functionality a disabled

**What i have**:

1. native mobile app that has user signup and signin functionality
2. api server consumed by the app
3. keycloack instance

*signup functionality* is done by *api server*, it is a keycloak confidencial client that can create users
*signin* is done by the *mobile app* directly with a post call to keycloak `/token` endpoind that returns access token

all good, now i have a token that can be consumed by my api server and i know that it is a registered user with unconfirmed email address

**The problem** is that user don't receive any Welcome/Confirm email, but: if user goes to keycloak LogIn webpage and try to login with newly created user then he receives an email from Keycloak, but for LogIn through api there are no emails. Is there any way so solve this? Am i doing something wrong?

The only way to request user to verify emails is by requesting "Verify Email" action, but if i do this then user can't login with unverified email anymore

Login is done with `POST` to `/auth/realms/realm/protocol/openid-connect/token` and with `{grant_type: 'password', password: 'string', username: 'string'}` body

Calling `PUT /{realm}/users/{id}/send-verify-email` seems to behaves the same like requesting `Verify Email` to `/execute-actions-email`

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a few years late for this answer, but for anyone who comes here in the future, the devs answered in this thread [here](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-5034)

> This is a limitation with the execute actions endpoint and it uses a
> generic email. It's not a bug, rather a limitation

And that's it. They have a specific endpoint just to send an email of verification but it's only a wrapper to the endpoint `execute-actions-email`